# Wrong version of clang - how to update

Tags: xcode

I have XCode 5.1.1 installed, osx 11.9.4. I have no other versions of xcode on the machine. But somehow I have clang version 2.1! I need a more updated one and cannot figure out how to make the upgrade.

```
delphi$ llvm-g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)

delphi$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
```

if I do xcode-select --install I get the following:

```
delphi$ xcode-select -install
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

Comment: The option you're looking for is `--install` not `-install` (note the double "-").

Answer (score 2):

Possibly installing the latest command line tools will help? `xcode-select --install` from terminal.

Comment: I added the output of running that command to the question. There was no space here. I was able to install the latest version of clang using macports, but still I don't understand what is happening here.

Comment: Weird. Looks like your entire dev environment is old (`--install` wasn’t added that long ago). I guess you could try reinstalling xcode, but if you’ve got what you need through ports it’s probably not worth it.

Comment: How did macports install it needs the latest Xcode command line tools to build - and not its own clang